# Shifting the position of bars in a horizontal bar chart in Flot

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I have 2 charts that are generated in Flot. [image: Sample charts]

I would like to move the bar in the chart with 1 bar away from the x-axis. I would like it to have gaps similar to the graph with 10 bars.  For example, is there a simpler way of specifying that I want the bar to be 10 pixels away from the y-axis?

This is the code that generates these charts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./flot/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .graph-container.store-container {
            height: 180px !important;
        }
        .graph-container.operator-container {
            height: 450px !important;
        }

        #top-stores-plot-numbers {
            height: 70px !important;
        }
        #top-operators-plot-numbers {
            height: 340px !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var plotOptions = {
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.7,
                        align: "center",
                        horizontal: true
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 2,
                    axisMargin: 10,
                    autoscaleMargin: 0.05
                },
                xaxis: {
                    autoscaleMargin:0.1,
                    min: 0,
                    ticks: 2
                }
            };

            var sn_data = [
                    [ 6087, "ACME Store"],
            ];
            var sn_ticks = [
                    [ 0, "ACME Store"],
            ];
            var sn_options = plotOptions;
            sn_options["yaxis"]["ticks"] = sn_ticks;
            sn_options["yaxis"]["max"] = 1;
            $.plot("#top-stores-plot-numbers", [ sn_data ], sn_options);

            var on_data = [
                    [ 50, "CRISTINA"],
                    [ 68, "CASHIER2"],
                    [ 96, "MIESZKO"],
                    [ 115, "CASHIER1"],
                    [ 209, "TRAINING 1"],
                    [ 379, "JADE"],
                    [ 640, "HOST1"],
                    [ 711, "CAROLINA"],
                    [ 795, "SUPERVISER"],
                    [ 1376, "TRAINING"],
            ];
            var on_ticks = [
                    [ 0, "CRISTINA"],
                    [ 1, "CASHIER2"],
                    [ 2, "MIESZKO"],
                    [ 3, "CASHIER1"],
                    [ 4, "TRAINING 1"],
                    [ 5, "JADE"],
                    [ 6, "HOST1"],
                    [ 7, "CAROLINA"],
                    [ 8, "SUPERVISER"],
                    [ 9, "TRAINING"],
            ];
            var on_options = plotOptions;
            on_options["yaxis"]["ticks"] = on_ticks;
            on_options["yaxis"]["max"] = 10;
            $.plot("#top-operators-plot-numbers", [on_data], on_options);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="graph-container store-container">
        <h2>Top 10 by Number</h2>
        <div id="top-stores-plot-numbers" class="graph-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-container operator-container">
        <h2>Top 10 by Number</h2>
        <div id="top-operators-plot-numbers" class="graph-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the  `autoscaleMargin` between graphs, not the `max` for the y-axis.

When you have 1 bar, set it to `0.5`.  When you have 10 bars, set it to `0.05`.  Take out any mention of `yaxis.max` and that should do it.

I changed your yaxis object to look like this in `plotOptions`:

```
            yaxis: {
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 2,
                autoscaleMargin: 0.5
            }
```

That's all you need for the 1 bar graph.

Before calling `$.plot` for the 2nd graph, change the `autoscaleMargin` like so:

```
            on_options["yaxis"]["autoscaleMargin"] = 0.05;
```

That's it, see it in action (minus the categories plugin): http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/tVmTt/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean that the `autoscaleMargin` should be set to C/n where C is a constant and n is the number of items? In this case C would be 0.5 so when there is 1 item 0.5/1 = 0.5, and when there are 10 items 0.5/10 = 0.05? Will this hold true for an arbitrary number of items?

Comment: I had the same thought, but I'm not 100% sure!

Comment: That's my one criticism of the otherwise excellent flot. It's so complex to configure and the documentation isn't exactly clear on things.

Comment: Hi, This setting is working fine for bar chart but not able to scale for line chart. Can you please tell us that, how can we set autoscalemargin for line chart in flot chart.